# Override a column value with django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a table as below -

```
name| age |
----|-----|
A   | 50  |
B   | 60  |
C   | 70  |
```

My Model class is -

```
class Persons(models.Model):
    p_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False)
    p_age = models.IntegerField(null=False)

objects = ManagerEx()

class Meta:
    db_table = u'persons'
```

I want to query the table with something like -

```
persons = Persons.objects.all()
```

But the names should be overridden with 'anonymous' so that for each person object p_name evaluates to 'anonymous'

```
for person in persons:
    name = person.p_name # For all objects name should equal to 'anonymous'
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Surely that's something you would do when you output the data, isn't it?

Comment: I can do this with sql. e.g select cast('anonymous' as varchar(32)) as p_name, p_age from persons. I am looking for a way to to this with django queryset

Comment: But why? A queryset isn't useful until you output it.

Comment: I am using django ORM in a backend project and there is an algorithm which works on the queryset returned from this. The behavior of the algorithm will be undefined if the value of p_name field is not 'anonymous' and I don't have an option to change the records in DB. The algorithm is generic which works on other data as well. I can not modify it either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `annotate`:

```
from django.db.models import Value, CharField

def get_anonymous:
    persons = Persons.objects.all()
    return persons.annotate(p_name=Value('anonymous', output_field=CharField()))
```

(using CharField as output because same type you used in `Persons` model

or if you want to have some conditions (hide name for kids only):

```
return queryset.annotate(
            p_name=Case(When(
                p_age__gte=18,
                then=F('p_name')),
                default=Value('anonymous'),
                output_field=CharField()
            ))
```

in second case remember to import also `Case` and `When` from `django.db.models`

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I answered you after 6 years :) But I found your question facing same problem, so after I solved it I wanted to share my experience.

Comment: When I do this I get `ValueError: The annotation 'my_field_name' conflicts with a field on the model.`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it in your template, as simple as:

```
<Table>
    <Th>
        <Td>Name</Td>
        <Td>Age</Td>
    </Th>
{% for person in persons %}
    <Tr>
        <Td>Anonymous</Td>
        <Td>person.p_age</Td>
    </Tr>
{% endfor %}
</Table>
```

If you want to do it in your views, you can do it with a raw query as you have said in comments.

Comment: Question was about queryset, not template